# How to call a wait pointer in Japanese?

Tags: words, translation, terminology, computing

In Japanese, how to call a [wait pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_pinwheel)?

I am talking about a computer mouse pointer which becomes a spinning wheel or hourglass (depending on the OS) when the application is busy processing something, or frozen:

[image][image][image]

After discussion with 3 Japanese people, apparently ウェイトカーソル is acceptable but there might be something better.

Comment: In Java, I've seen `待ち状態のカーソル`

Comment: How would one translate "Spinning Beachball of Waiting"?  That's what I call it.

Comment: That's an interesting question...I actually don't know if I've ever heard of it called that in English, just usually "the hourglass" or "the spinning beach-ball", etc

Answer (score 6):

According to [Microsoft Language Portal](http://www.microsoft.com/language/ja-jp/Search.aspx?sString=wait%20cursor&langID=ja-jp), they call it “wait cursor” in English and “待機カーソル” in Japanese in the documentation for Visual Studio 2008 SP1, 2010, and 2012.  I am not sure how popular this term is among users.

Comment: I've certainly never heard of either "wait pointer" or "wait cursor" in English, and I consider myself very computer-literate, so I'm inclined to believe it's not very popular except amongst people who have read that documentation. (More flippantly, but equally sincerely, I imagine that in practice the Japanese at least use the same *sort* of language we do to describe it, such as "beach ball of death" or "oh for ****'s sake that stupid ******* egg timer ******* again".)

Comment: @Billy: When it looked like an hourglass, it was definitely called 砂時計カーソル (hourglass cursor) or 砂時計アイコン (hourglass icon).  I doubt that this name is used anymore in Mac or Windows because neither OS uses the hourglass shape by default.  Now I might informally refer to it as something along 時間がかかるときに表示されるくるくる回るやつ (that spinning one that is shown when the computer is taking time).